# MongoDB and MongoRuby: Sorting on mapreduce

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mapreduce

I am currently trying to do a simple mapreduce over some documents stored in MongoDB. I use

```
map = BSON::Code.new "function() { emit(this.userid, 1); }"
```

for the mapping and

```
reduce = BSON::Code.new "function(key, values) {
   var sum = 0;
   values.forEach(function(value) {
    sum += value;
   });
   return sum;
}"
```

for the reduction. This works fine when I call `map_reduce` the following way:

```
output = col.map_reduce(map, reduce, # col is the collection in mongodb, e.g. db.users
            {
                :out => {:inline => true},
                :raw => true
            }
          )
```

Now to the real question: How can I use the upper call to `map_reduce` to enable sorting? [The manual says](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#map_reduce-instance_method), that I must use `sort` and an array of `[key, direction]` pairs. I guessed the following should work, but it doesn't:

```
output = col.map_reduce(map, reduce,
            {
                :sort => [["value", Mongo::ASCENDING]],
                :out => {:inline => true},
                :raw => true
            }
          )
```

Do I have to choose another datatype? The option also doesn't work (same error), when using an empty `[]`, although the manual says that is the default for the option. Unfortunately the error message from MongoDB doesn't help too much:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.3.1/lib/mongo/db.rb:506:in `command': Database command 'mapreduce' failed: {"assertion"=>"sort has to be blank or an Object", "assertionCode"=>13609, "errmsg"=>"db assertion failure", "ok"=>0.0} (Mongo::OperationFailure)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.3.1/lib/mongo/collection.rb:576:in `map_reduce'
    from ./mapreduce.rb:26:in `<main>'
```

If you need the full runnable code, please say so in the comments. I exclude it for now as it only contains the initialization of a connection to mongodb and initialization of the collection `col` by querying a database.

Comment: what about  :sort => {"value", Mongo::ASCENDING}..

Comment: That changes the error message to `could not create cursor over [the collection] for query : {} sort : { value: 1 }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `BSON::OrderedHash` and it will work.

```
output = col.map_reduce(map, reduce,
    {
         :sort => BSON::OrderedHash.new[{"value", Mongo::ASCENDING}],
         :out => {:inline => true},
         :raw => true
    }
)
```